# How to prevent jsp from unauthorize access

Tags: angular, jsp

In past, I can use server session to control the JSP access.
However, I want to use the Angular framework to build the web front end.
And using the JSP to web back end.

I want the users cannot access some JSPs before they log in the system.
However, I don't know how to prevent the JSPs from unauthorized access in this situation.

Is JSON Web Token(JWT) can be used in this situation?
However, some articles suggest do not use JWT in session control.

I am confusing about it.

[image]

Comment: How are you thinking to integrate Angular and JSP? The two don't really work with each other. I wouldn't call JSP a back-end in this context - it's a server-side rendered application. You would generally have some REST services / API on the back-end which Angular consumes. In that scenario you can use JWT for user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Angular calls REST APIs rather than load JSPs/ASPs.
If you don't wanna expose some of your Angular routes to unauthorised users, you can do Angular router guards.
If you don't want some of your Java APIs, if you have these things, to be called by unauthorised users, I would recommend using JWTs.

Comment: I want to clarify that I have created some Angular services for getting data from a server through some JSP pages. Is it  a correct REST API implementation?

Comment: The JWT is confusing me the most, It can be decoded by any program easily. It contains the encode algorithm in the token also. As I my understanding, that mean anyone can create a token to gain access to the JAVA API. Some articles states that JWT just for ensure the data does not changed by third party.

Comment: @HKKNVB JSP pages are the Views of Java MVC, not a REST API endpoints. A rest API endpoint only returns a JSON.

Comment: @HKKNVB JWT doesn't contain the encryption algorithm in it. You generate JWT at the server with an algorithm of your choice. The user won't know. Plus, there are anti-forgery measures. You might wanna google that out.

Comment: For the encryption algorithm, you may refer the attached screen dump. My JSP output is a JSON.

Comment: @HKKNVB That is interesting! Sounds like a compromised solution to migrating off Java. Anyway, you would need an Angular router guard on the client side if only one or some of your Angular routes call that JSP. If that JSP only allows the access from authorised users, then I guess JWT won't work because it is not an API endpoint. But I guess you can mimick that. On login, your Java issue Angular a token. And on request of this JSP, you pass back this token and validate it.

Comment: @HKKNVB you can encrypt the jwt, send it to the client. When the client sends it back to the server, decrypt it first and then validate it. The example you showed me doesn't have this layer so chances are that you can get to the content of it.

Comment: Do you mean I need to create a RESTful Web Service on Tomcat for Angular access?

Comment: @HKKNVB Yes, exactly. That is how Angular is supposed to work.

Comment: Really? Would you tell me what is/are the difference between  RESTful Web Service  and JSP?And Why  RESTful Web Service suppose to work with Angular?